# Creating an Arbitrary Custom Transform Orientation in Python

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

Is there a way to create an arbitrary transform orientation in Python?

The API function [`bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation) only allows the orientation to be created from the current view or the selected object.  In my particular case, I want it along the line between two objects.

My initial thought is to create the transform orientation (call it 'mytransform') with `bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation()`, and then directly set `bpy.context.scene.orientations['mytransform'].matrix`.  But:

1. I don't know if this is kosher (I try to avoid mucking directly with the data structures when possible).
2. It has some disadvantages, mainly that I can't run it from the Python console for testing (`create_orientation()` only works in a 3DView context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test code to create orientation and use in all 3d views in the current (context) screen.

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Matrix
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

# create view

bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation(name="Frank", overwrite=True)
orientation = scene.orientations.get("Frank")
print(orientation)

# make up some matrix
# rotated 45 degrees on (1, 1, 1) axis
m = Matrix.Rotation(radians(45), 3, (1, 1, 1))
orientation.matrix = m

# find 3d views to set to "Frank"
screen = context.screen
views = [area.spaces.active for area in screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
for view in views:
    view.transform_orientation = orientation.name
```

Note you can [override operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/6105?s=1%7C0.0000#6105) to "trick" them into thinking they are running in another area.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was thinking.  Regarding the override (I just ran across that in the docs yesterday), I assume `bpy.context.area.type` will tell me if the current context is correct; but if it's not, and I have more than one VIEW_3D open, how do I tell which is which (maybe this warrants a separate question)?

Comment: Also, just as an addendum (since it took me a while to find), the following seems to work for setting the matrix from two points:
    q = (pt[1] - pt[0]).to_track_quat('X', 'Z')
    C.scene.orientations['BASELINE'].matrix = q.to_matrix()